# FreeRDP Right-Ctrl keyboard-ungrab (seemingly) not working in 22.10 / X11

Tags: rdp

In FreeRDP a Right-Ctrl is supposed to "ungrab" the keyboard so that the next keypress goes to the host and not the remote, [more info here](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/pull/3622). This seems to be not working in 22.10, using X11. Can someone else confirm whether this works for them? Tryin' to decide whether I should spend time debugging my own machine vs filing a bug report.